# como comparar valor null/nulo quando digito caracter em C

Tags: c, linux

```
    printf("\nteste -> "); 
    scanf("%i", &opAjuda);
```

/* opAjuda é pra receber um inteiro, mas quero fazer um if aqui,
 dizendo que se a pessoa escrever um caracter ao inves de inteiro, ele vai pra tela ajuda e mostra a mensagem que ta dentro do if. E então a pessoa tem que digitar de novo, no caso, um numero inteiro. */

```
    if (opAjuda == 0) {

        /*system("clear");
        telaAjuda ();
        printf("\n\tTENTE NOVAMENTE!\n");
        printf("\n\tOBS: Digite um numero relacionado ao topico que deseja.\n");
        subMenu_Ajuda();*/

         //telaPrincipal ();

         printf("\n%s", opAjuda); //teste pra ver o q estava imprimindo

    } else {

       //Aqui fica o meu switch case
    }
```

Quando eu digito um valor numerico, o programa funciona certinho, porém quando eu digito algum caracter (que não seja os especiais q ja tenho definido e já fiz os ifs pra ele) então quando digito um caracter ele fica em um loop infinito.
Acontece q quando fiz o teste pra ver o que estava imprimindo quando digitava um caracter ele imprime um valor NULL (nulo), tentei representar esse valor no if mas não estou conseguindo.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

OBS: Quero fazer isso pois estou pensando no usuário, no programa está escrito e tem dicas dizendo que é para digitar um numero, mas nem todos os usuários seguem o que está escrito, e quero que o programa esteja preparado caso aconteça.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quiser garantir que o usuário digite apenas números você deve fazer o tratamento do `scanf` da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int clean_stdin()
{
    while (getchar()!='\n');
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num =0;
    char c;

    printf("\nDigite um numero: ");
    if (( scanf("%d%c", &num, &c) != 2 || c != '\n' ) && ( clean_stdin()) )
        printf("\nVoce deve digitar somente numeros.\n\n");
    else
        printf("\nNumero digitado: %d\n\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Caso o usuário digitar uma string como `21dff` então você terá que limpar seu `stdin`, a função `clean_stdin()` faz isso para você.

**Explicação**

*Exemplo 1*: Se o usuário digitar `abcd` e em seguida `ENTER` o `scanf` retornara `0` e nada sera capturado.

*Exemplo 2*: Se o usuário digitar `40` e em seguida `ENTER` o `scanf` retornara 2 ou seja dois elementos foram capturados, e `"%d"` recebeu o valor `40` e `"%c"` recebeu `"\n"`.

*Exemplo 3*: Se o usuário digitar `32abc` e em seguida `ENTER`, o `scanf` retornara dois elementos, e `"%d"` recebeu o valor `32` e `"%c"` recebeu `"a"`.

Assim você pode garantir que o usuário digite apenas números.

Fonte da pesquisa [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099473/how-to-scanf-only-integer-and-repeat-reading-if-the-user-enter-non-numeric-chara).

Comment: Obrigada Dener, essa explicação vai me ajudar já. ;)

Answer (score 2):

A função scanf retorna um inteiro, sendo valor 1 quando a leitura não houver erro.
Exemplo comum.

```
int res=0, in=0;

res = scanf("%d",&in);
if(res==1){
  //seu codigo
}
else{
  //tratar o erro
}
```

para o seu problema a solução seria criar um loop sendo a condição de saida o 
retorno da função scanf.

Exemplo:

```
while(scanf("%d",&in)!=1){
   prinf("valor inválido, digite um numero inteiro\n");
}
```

> obs.: como você colocou a tag linux, acredito que esse seja seu
>   sistema operacional. Logo quando tiver alguma dúvida em relação alguma
>   função em C você pode dar uma olhada na documantação, usando o
>   programa `man` que ja vem instalado em todas as distribuições linux.
>   Abra o terminal e digite `man nome_da_funcao`, exemplo: `man scanf`

Comment: Obrigada Skywalker ;) Entendi, vou tentar desse jeito. Legal, vou procurar isso no terminal do linux. Bem interessante.